# Won't let me connect my clash of clans account to my iOS from android

Tags: clash-of-clans

I lost my clash of clans account a while back and every time I try to link it to my iOS it says something about "I have spent money on this account" or something like that. Someone please help!

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry this usually happens try to re log the WI-FI. If that doesn't work try shutting down the device. Sometimes this happens is if you are using a phone they are not always the best for games that require WI-FI or that are multiplayer

Comment: Phones are not bad for WIFI games. Also, what do you mean by "Re-log the WIFI"?